# How can I record my iPhone's screen?

Tags: applications, iphone

I'm wondering how I could record the screen of my iPhone **without jailbreaking**? Are there any Apps that will do this? I know how to take a screen shot but I don't know how to record video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do it without jailbreaking. Because of the security restrictions on what apps can access, and particularly the limited functionality when running in the background, I'm pretty sure it's impossible without jailbreaking (and maybe even if you do jailbreak).

If you're looking to make a screen-cast or something similar, the technique I've heard is popular (at least with [Adam Lisagor](http://sandwichvideo.com/), who does a lot of iOS app videos) is using the iPhone simulator included with Xcode.

Comment: This answer is no longer current.  See here for an update:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151305/how-to-record-iphone-screen-on-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite, you can connect the iPhone to your Mac using the Lightning connector, and it will be available as a video camera. Then you can record video of what happens on the screen using QuickTime Player.

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/)

With previous versions of iOS and OS X, you can use AirPlay mirroring on your phone and  an AirPlay receiver/recorder like [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) or [X-Mirage](http://x-mirage.com/x-mirage/).

Comment: while I see all the Pokemon Go recordings done by Android phones, if I want to do that with my iPhone, I really cannot easily take my iPhone on one hand, the Macbook on another hand, and then chase down that Lapras

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apple 30 pin to HDMI cable (meant for iPads) and hook it up to a Tivo. This will only work if your using an iPhone 4, no other iPhones will work with the cable.

Comment: I'm wondering how Steve Jobs did it when he was showing the iPhone? I think there is actually a cable for all iPhones (it's on the Apple site for like $29.99) but I was hoping that there's an App for it but since there isn't the cable would probably be the only way. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I believe Apple has its own customized hardware for keynote purposes. The Apple HDMI connector is a good idea that I didn't think about, but unfortunately it only supports mirroring on the iPad 2 (and presumably the next-gen iPhone). On the iPhone 4, you're restricted to just showing content as a secondary display, like slides or videos, not the screen itself.

It looks like you can hack the iPhone 4 to mirror the display, but it requires jailbreaking and some other tweaks. [Guide here](http://news.imodzone.net/2011/04/how-to-enable-mirror-display-on-ipad-1-iphone-4-ipod-touch/)

Comment: You can buy [Lightning to HDMI adapters](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD826ZM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter) too. It's not limited to the 30 pin connector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OS X app like [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) or [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com) to make your Mac simulate an AirPlay display. Then you select your Mac as an external AirPlay display on your iPhone. AirServer and Reflector provide features to record the output.

OS X 10.10 Yosemite has an iOS screen recording feature built into QuickTime.