# How to record iPhone/iPad screen on macOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, macos, catalina

OS X Yosemite brought support for recording iPhone/iPad screen natively without having to using AirPlay applications like AirServer or Reflector.

How do I record the iPhone screen on macOS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I AirPlay mirror my iPhone screen to my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139989/how-do-i-airplay-mirror-my-iphone-screen-to-my-macbook-pro)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro How is this the same? This question is clearly about screen recording whilst the question you've mentioned is about "Airplay Mirror" for which answer is a free solution.

Comment: I may have misjudged my duplicate flag. It's less that the question is duplicate and more so the accepted answer for both is a duplicate. Neither question is an *exact* duplicate, they're just fairly similar.

Comment: In hindsight, it might be better if the other question is closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Neither question is a duplicate of the other, screen recording and screen mirroring may have different solutions/answers.

Comment: xcrun simctl io booted screenshot
To record a video, use the recordVideo operation:

xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <VideoFILENAME>.<extension>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Requirements

- iPhone/ iPad running **iOS 8 and above** `(Lightning port ONLY)`
- **Mac running OSX 10.10, OSX 10.11, macOS 10.12 and above.**

### How to Record iPhone/iPad Screen on macOS

1. Connect the iPhone/iPad to Mac via USB
2. Open the QuickTime Player on the Mac
3. Select `File > New Movie Recording`

[image: Recording iPhone with Quicktime]

4. Quicktime will default select iSight camera, click on the arrow alongside the record button to select the iPhone/iPad.
5. Click on the record button to record the iPhone/iPad Screen