# How to record a screen film of an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, screen, screen-capture, video-capture

I would like to record a screen film of my iPad. If possible, I would like to include my spoken comments.

How can I do that ?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151305/how-to-record-iphone-screen-on-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 4):

Starting with iOS 11, screen recording is a [built-in feature](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-ios-11-built-in-screen-recording-feature/). It also includes an option to turn the microphone on during the session, by long-pressing or hard-pressing the screen recording button.

[image]

<s>iOS 11 is still in beta but it's now in *public* beta which means you don't need to be a developer to [enroll and test it](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/).</s>

Answer (score 2):

You connect your iPad to a mac, open up iTunes and quicktime. in quicktime, go to file-new movie recording.

there will be a little down arrow next to the record button, click the down arrow and choose your iPad.  then hit the record button.

I don't know if this works with 30 pin iPads. i know it works with lightning ones.  if you don't have a mac, i think you're out of luck unless you jailbreak.

Comment: I have an iPad mini with Lightning cable. But I am looking for a solution on the iPad.

Comment: This solution with the Mac requires Yosemite and iOS 8, I think. And I have neither.

Comment: Now, I have an all new iPad, on iOS 8, and I am interested in a solution to record his screen, preferably without any other machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an iPad with a lightning connector and iOS 8 you can open QuickTime on your Yosemite Mac and make a recording. If you don't have a Mac or a iPad with lightning connector you could use Reflector which is using Airplay. [Link to Reflector application](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/)

Comment: My iPad has a Lightning connector, but not iOS 8. I will try Reflector, which looks nice. However, I would prefer a solution needing only the iPad.

Comment: The iPad can not record its own screen. You need to have a computer that do the recording. This is not an recommendation but I know that that it is possible to record the screen if you have an jailbroken iPad. But again, that is nothing I recommend.

Comment: I don't do jailbreak.

Comment: Try with the Reflector application and record on your Mac/PC. As I said before the iPad can't (it's an missing function in my opinion) record it's own screen.

Comment: Now I have an iPad on iOS 8, and I am interested in a solution for recording his screen, preferably without any other machine.