# How to record iPhone/iPad screen in Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, windows

[As seen in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151305/how-to-record-iphone-ipad-screen-on-os-x-yosemite), it's possible to record an iPhone or iPad using a Mac by using Quicktime's recording features. This unfortunately isn't an option on Windows, as Quicktime for Windows was [discontinued fo in 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837) without ever adding this feature.

**Is there any way to record an iPhone/iPad screen on a Windows PC?**

Comment: Yosemite was released in 2014, so newer versions of QuickTime should have the same features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/08/how-to-enable-screen-recording-ios-11-without-a-computer/), iOS 11 includes a dedicated **Screen Recorder** which can be used without connecting to a Mac.

> ### Enabling screen recording on iOS 11
>
> 1. Launch **Settings** → **Control Center** → **Customize Controls**.
> 2. Scroll down in the list and add **Screen Recording**
> 3. Close Settings
>
> [image: iOS 11 - Enable screen recording in settings]
>
> 4. Swipe-up from the bottom of the display to reveal Control Center
> 5. Tap Screen Recording button to immediately begin recording (or 3D Touch to bring up menu)
>
> [image: iOS 11 - Screen recording in action]

- Source: [9toMac - How to enable screen recording on iOS 11 without a computer](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/08/how-to-enable-screen-recording-ios-11-without-a-computer/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software like [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/Usage/Recording) or [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/win/).

The software simulates an AirPlay receiver (like an AppleTV) and you select this receiver on you iOS device.

These are commercial applications but you may give their trials a try.